# Tabular alternate left and center alignment?

Tags: tables, alignment

Attempting to alternate between left alignment and center alignment in table. Wish to have vertical rule between columns. Following code loses vertical rule because of use of \multicol to achieve alternating alignments.

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Edit: correction per comment @egreg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\mc\multicolumn
\DeclareMathOperator{\lo}{\mathrm{o}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
 Coordonnées du point O & Coordonnées de l’axe o \\
\mc1c{$x=\lo,\;y=\lo.$} & \mc1c{$u=\lo,\;v=\lo.$}\\
  Équation de l’axe $x$ & Équation du point $X$  \\
        \mc1c{$y=\lo.$} & \mc1c{$v=\lo.$}        \\
  Équation de l’axe $y$ & Équation du point $Y$  \\
        \mc1c{$x=\lo.$} & \mc1c{$u=\lo.$}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: what I have]

[image]

Comment: I understand that you want to emulate an old book, but using `o` in place of `0` is wrong.

Comment: @egreg The author explains his notation beginning here: 52. Nous représenterons les points par des lettres
majuscules, les droites par des minuscules. Un point
sera parfois désigné par les noms de deux droites s’y
coupant, et une droite par les noms de deux de ses points. and continues for several paragraphs. It makes sense to me, but ... a link to the article scan is [Nouvelles annales de mathématiques :  Série 3 : Tome 4 (1885)](http://www.numdam.org/item/NAM_1885_3_4__110_0.pdf)

Comment: I was objecting to 0 turned into o, not to the letter o itself. In “Cordonnées de l’axe *o*” you have a letter o; in the subsequent formulas there are zeros (in “oldstyle” format).

Comment: @egreg Ah! math mode? will attempt an edit. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the vertical bar back in with the multicolumn, by way of `\mc1{c|}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\mc\multicolumn
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
 Coordonnées du point O & Coordonnées de l’axe o \\
    \mc1{c|}{$x=o,\;y=o.$} & \mc1c{$u=o,\;v=o.$}    \\
  Équation de l’axe $x$ & Équation du point $X$  \\
          \mc1{c|}{$y=o.$} & \mc1c{$v=o.$}          \\
  Équation de l’axe $y$ & Équation du point $Y$  \\
          \mc1{c|}{$x=.o$} & \mc1c{$u=o.$}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]